# Implementing rate limiting headers from API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm implementing an API using AWS API Gateway. I'm using native API Keys and Usage Plans to rate limit clients. Yet, I would like to add data usage information to my API responses, something like the `X-RateLimit-Remaining` and `X-RateLimit-Reset` headers.

I asked to AWS support if there wasn't any native implementation, as this is (IMO at least) a very common requirement. There is not.

I then took a look on implementing these headers using some calls to [AWS usage API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_usage) (even if I don't really like adding an API call overhead to each of my requests). But I need the API key ID, not the API key value (the only one I have in my requests). According to this [AWS thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244641), there probably won't be any lookup method by API key value.

I can imagine only two solutions at this step:

- Loop through the list of all API keys to find the correct one. But that won't scale.
- Handling rate limiting data on our side (using a Redis server to keep track of all calls for instance). But that would represent a lot of work and expose us to high risks of de-synchronization.

How are you sharing the data usage within your API responses? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @Jonathan did you find any way for this ?